# Twilio get number of sender in twiml or webhook laravel

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I have a webhook that saves the sender number once the webhook is triggered.
How can I get the number of the sender that triggered the webhook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already found the answer to my question.

```
public function receivedSms(Request $request){

   $response = new Twiml();


      echo $request['From'],
      echo $request['Body']

   return response($response)
      ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/08/receive-sms-php-twilio.html